# What is primitive unit cell in overlapping pattern?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

[image]

In this image what could be primitive unit cell because I can see much overlap and can't find any element which fills the space on repetition. Is there something I am missing regarding definition of primitive cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When learning about crystalline structures, it is pretty frequent to confuse the crystalline structure and the underlying Bravais lattice.

The primitive unit cell is a concept of the Bravais lattice, i.e., to the lattice obtained by the minimum independent translations, which are symmetry operations for the structure. Therefore, the starting point for identifying the primitive unit cell in 2D is to look for two independent translations that bring a point into an equivalent point.

An example of a possible primitive unit cell is in the following figure.
[image]

From which is evident that the Bravais lattice is a triangular lattice (two equal length translations forming an angle of $60$ degrees). Of course, alternative choices for the basis vectors or their origin are possible.
The important thing is that the simplest repetition unit that must fill the space is not an entire element of the drawing but the region inside the rhombus.